# change configurable product detail page layout

Tags: configurable-product, product-view

is it possible to change layout of product detail page of configurable products via custom modules instead of changing config.xml and other core files .

please prodive better wayto do this

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can change easy by layout handler. when magento is call a  configurable products it add `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` handler to current layout

ex:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
 <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2column-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

create local.xml at app/design/frontent/yourpackage/yourtempate/layout/ and add this code

Comment: can i do it vai module instead of changing code file

Comment: yes..............

Comment: how can update answer

Comment: for configurable product i want to call product.info.options.wrapper to left of image how can i do it .
via changes in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Go
`app/design/frontent/yourpackage/yourtempate/layout/catalog.xml`

**Search for** "`catalog_product_view`"

You can change template name here in place of "2columns-left.phtml"

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

Comment: Patil  check  question properly.. the question is indicate that the the template are only apply  on configurable product